# permission denied when renaming file in linux at /var/www/html

Tags: linux, putty, pscp

I am very new to linux and am using putty and pscp to move files to a live hosted directory. I would like to rename my recently uploaded dist folder to its actual project name using mv but get a permission denied error. What is the safest and most reasonable way to arrange these files so I can rename them?

```
lawton@lawtonb:/var/www/html$ ls -la
total 268
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root     4096 Aug 30 16:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root     4096 Aug 18 23:05 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lawton lawton 253276 Aug 27 18:06 bundle.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root     4096 Aug 30 16:42 dist
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       17 Aug 18 23:24 info.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root     4096 Aug 27 18:59 react-youtube

lawton@lawtonb:/var/www/html$ mv dist BTC_Sorter
mv: cannot move 'dist' to 'BTC_Sorter': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one-time rename, your best course of action would be to run `mv` with `sudo`, like this:

`sudo mv dist BTC_Sorter`

If, however, you'd like to have permissions for your user or group, you should do [some reading about](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Changing_ownership) `chown` (The link belongs to the Arch Linux wiki, but should be useful regardless of your distro).

In your particular case, the directory `dist` is owned both by the user and the group `root`, hence why you'd need to use `sudo`, `chown` or simply the `root` account.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the owner of the file, you need execute the command with  sudo

```
sudo mv src dest
```